# Java lambda parameters: how can I prevent using parameters from outer scope?

Tags: java, lambda, closures

I do know how lambda & parameters work in Java. 
The problem is that in the body of a lambda, I *want be enforced* to use only the lambda parameters, and (if possible) let compiler throw error when using outer scope variables.

Example:

Bad:

```
    int outerInt = 3;
    Predicate<String> lamb = s -> { 
        return outerInt==0 && s.equals("x"); //using outerInt -> bad!
    };

    bool res = lamb.test("?");
```

Good:

```
    int outerInt = 3;
    BiPredicate<String, Integer> lamb = (s, i) -> { 
        return i==0 && s.equals("x"); //using lambda parameter 'i' instead of outerInt-> good!
    };

    bool res = lamb.test("?", outerInt);
```

How would you design your code, or can we somehow setup the java compiler to enforce this approach?

Comment: You're more or less asking: how to use a lambda without actually using the lambda; you're gonna need **some** sort of input.

Comment: No, you cannot selectively turn off language features for yourself in Java. This would need to be enforced in code review. Maybe you could write a static analyzer for this and hook it into your build.

Answer (score 3):

You want something that actually goes against the nature of lambdas:

> The body of a lambda expression has the same scope as a nested block.

*[Source.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2303960&seqNum=7)*

If you want to separate scopes, put functionality into separate methods.

Comment: OP could probably put each lambda into it's own wrapper class that composes the lambda, but that would create a lot of extra files for the "privilege" of having no accessible variables from outside said lambda. To make it clear, *it's a bad idea and you shouldn't do it*.

Comment: When you start putting lambdas into wrapper classes, I'd argue using normal methods would be easier.

Comment: I didn't say it was *smart*, just that it is possible.

Comment: Of course, I didn't think you'd think that'd be smart. Just wanted to make sure no-one actually does that ;-).